# Can we access STDClass object with bracket notation in Lumen laravel freamwork

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, stdclass

code snippet as below:

```
$userinfo = DB::table('userinfo')
            ->select('addressid', 'extradetailid', 'mobileno')
            ->where('mobileno', $detail['mobileno'])
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

$users = DB::table('user')
            ->select('name', 'age', 'contact', 'addressid','extradetailid')
            ->where(function ($qb1) use ($userinfo) {
                $qb1->whereIn('addressid', array_column($userinfo, 'addressid'))
                    ->orWhereIn('extradetailid', array_column($userinfo, 'extradetailid'));
            })
            ->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();


   

 foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user['addressid'] != null) { // getting error here Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
            
        }
}
```

My PHP version is 7.3
I am using the AMPP apache server.

I want to use an object with the bracket notation. Is there any way to do that in the PHP lumen laravel framework?

Comment: type cast it to array

Comment: Why do you want to use it with bracket notation? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? If you just want to access that field, write `$user->addressid`

Answer (score -1):

Before looping $users variable first try to convert it to array. Check if this works:

```
$users = json_decode(json_encode($users), true);
```

Comment: While this might work, I think it's bad advice, because this is a bad habit to get into. It's much better to understand how to use the data you're working with than force everything into a simple array structure.

Comment: @IMSoP You are right on data but I barely answered question. Your point is related to the question itself not to my answer.